# How to input average values calculated from specific non NA value columns into existing average column

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

![Text][Dataframe being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uthz9.png)

Please see the link for the dataframe image. I am trying to calculate the Average temp for the rows which are missing TempAvg values. Some rows have TempMin and TempMax and therefore the Avg temperature can be calculated using this. That being said I need to use the function to calculate TempAvg for rows where TempAvg does not already exist and would be an NA value. I run the risk of having new TempAvg values calculated for already existing values in the TempAvg column. I have tried to forumalte a for loop but after continued reading see this is not the best option. How would one go about this issue as the dataframe contains 13 million rows. Just to clarify I would want to keep as many rows as possible as checking rows where TempAvg is not NA shows only 2.5 million rows meaning a huge amount of data is lost if I drop TempMin & Max columns with NA values

```
sum(!is.na(Avg))
[1] 2535882
```

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can solve this with a `case_when` statement. Something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(TempAvg = case_when(
    !is.na(TempAvg) ~ TempAvg,
    TRUE ~ (TempMax + TempMin) / 2
  ))
```

With that code, you're saying, "Create a column called TempAvg, and fill it with the existing TempAvg values where they're not NA, otherwise fill it with the average between TempMax and TempMin"

Comment: `Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `TempAvg`.
x must be an integer vector, not a double vector` I keep getting this issue with the code

Comment: having tried to remove the first case_when it seems to have worked on some rows while others have the TempAvg removed completely

Comment: It sounds like maybe your columns aren't all the same class? You can force them to all be by doing something like this:
`mutate(across(c("TempAvg", "TempMax", "TempMin"), as.numeric))`
before your case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Following some trial and error the solution needed a simple fix

```
Weather2021 <- Weather2021 %>%
    mutate(TempAvg = case_when(
    !is.na(TempAvg) ~ as.numeric(TempAvg),
    !is.na(TempMax) & !is.na(TempMin) ~ (TempMax + TempMin) / 2))
```

the as.numeric conversion seemingly key